# Kendo DataSource with data used within grid has no data

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, datasource

I have a kendo datasource within MVC application written in C#. This kendo data source retrieves a list of states and corresponding time periods (as TimeSpan

```
    var statesDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id = id}))',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                console.log(result);
                CreateTestSetupUsageStatisticsChart();
                CreateTestSetupUsageStatisticsGrid();
            },
            error: function (xhr, error) {
                debugger;
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    },
```

Then I retrive data using `statesDataSource.fetch();` and can see request and response in Chrome Network tab. When I access data of this datasource i can see:

```
statesDataSource.data()
[
- nt.extend.init
    Duration: nt.extend.init
        Days: 0,
        Hours: 0,
        Milliseconds: 94,
        Minutes: 0,
        Seconds: 56,
        Ticks: 560940000,
        TotalDays: 0.0006492361111111111,
        TotalHours: 0.015581666666666666,
        TotalMilliseconds: 56094,
        TotalMinutes: 0.9349000000000001,
        TotalSeconds: 56.093999999999994
    HumanReadableDuration: "56s"
    State: "Broken"
    _events: Object
    parent: function (){return r
    uid: "4a9044ec-921c-48c7-9234-f569aacebc10"
    __proto__: i
+ nt.extend.init, 
+ nt.extend.init, 
+ nt.extend.init, 
+ nt.extend.init, 
+ nt.extend.init, 
+ nt.extend.init
]
```

So there are results. I would like to use them in kendo Grid and Chart but problem is, when I create a grid with the following command it's empty:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    datasource: statesDataSource,
    columns: [{
        field: "State",
        title: "State",
    }, {
        field: "HumanReadableDuration",
        title: "Duration"
    }]
});
```

When I access datasource from kendo using  $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data() it's empty as well. I also tried to use `datasource: { data: statesDataSource }` and `datasource: { data: statesDataSource.data() }` but with no success.

I also tried to use Datasource directly with kendo grid but with the same effect:

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        datasource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id = id}))',
                    dataType: "json",
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [{
            field: "State",
            title: "State",
        }, {
            field: "HumanReadableDuration",
            title: "Duration"
        }]
    });
```

This simply does not work. The data that I receive back from server is a proper JSON with structure:

```
[
{
    "State":"Broken",
    "Duration":
    {
        "Hours":0,
        "Minutes":0,
        "Seconds":56,
        "Milliseconds":94,
        "Ticks":560940000,
        "Days":0,
        "TotalDays":0.00064923611111111106,
        "TotalHours":0.015581666666666666,
        "TotalMilliseconds":56094,
        "TotalMinutes":0.93490000000000006,
        "TotalSeconds":56.093999999999994
    },
    "HumanReadableDuration":"56s"
},
...
]
```

Is it a problem with TimeSpan variable? Or is it something I'm missing right now? I'm fixated right now since I can't make it work since yesterday. Any new idea or insight would be very helpful.

Comment: have you tried adding `datasource.read()`

Comment: Yes, and it didn't changed anything. I've managed to display grid by typing in chrome's console (after page loaded and nothing really displayed) `$("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(statesDataSource)`. When I tried it on chart i got an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: State is not defined`. State is field from datasource (and it is there and always initialized properly by as a string).

Comment: that sounds like an ordering of actions error to me then.  I'd suggest pastebin'ing your whole view page.

Comment: Yeah please put all the code in reasonable blocks. You are going to need a schema with this data set. Please include that section.